# Recreating a renewenvironment using the \renewenvironment is creating a side effect!

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I have a buildin environment in a module `theorems-ams-bytype.inc` (in lyx) example, which i copied and created a duplicate with required changes for a environment called as `pitfall`.

```
Style Pitfall
        CopyStyle             Definition
        LatexName             pitfall
        LabelString           "Pitfall \thepitfall."
        Preamble
          \theoremstyle{definition}
          \newtheorem{pitfall}{\protect\pitfallname}[chapter]
          \renewcommand{\thepitfall}{\arabic{pitfall}} % this will number the pitfall number as normal 1,2, etc while if u remove this line then it would be chapterno.pitfall number. 
        EndPreamble
        Requires   amsthm
        LangPreamble
          \providecommand{\pitfallname}{_(Pitfall)}
        EndLangPreamble
        BabelPreamble
          \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\pitfallname}{_(Pitfall)}}
        EndBabelPreamble
        LabelCounter   pitfall
End
```

Now I add some nice decorations to this environment using the renewenvironment command. The code for this redefinition of the environment is as follows.

```
% for pitfall
    \mdfdefinestyle{pitfallstyle}{%
    linecolor=gray,middlelinewidth=7pt,%
    frametitlerule=false,%
    %tikzsetting={shading=axis,top color=gray!10},
    % apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
    %shade,left color=white, right color=gray!20}}}, frametitlerulecolor=gray!60,
    roundcorner=1pt,
    splittopskip=1cm,
    splitbottomskip=1cm,
    bottomline=false,
    leftline=false,
    rightline=false,
    backgroundcolor=gray!10,
    frametitlerulewidth=0pt,
    innertopmargin=\topskip, }
    % changes in pitfall environment
    \let\origpitfall\pitfall
    \let\endorigpitfall\endpitfall
    \renewenvironment{pitfall}{%
    % here you can make changes in the original pitfall class
    \begin{mdframed}[style=pitfallstyle] \origpitfall }{
    \endorigpitfall
    \end{mdframed}
     }
```

Now the trouble is if I don't use `\begin{pitfall} ... \end{pitfall}` in the entire document then there is an error. and the error is below.

[image]

Kindly help me understand.

Comment: You should show a complete (but minimal) LaTeX document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a timing problem; in any case, doing `\let\origpitfall=\pitfall` may hide a, well, pitfall.

You should be able to solve the problem by giving *another* name to the inner environment, say

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{pitfallx}{\protect\pitfallname}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thepitfallx}{\arabic{pitfallx}}
\providecommand{\pitfallname}{_(Pitfall)}
```

and define the "real" `pitfall` environment in terms of `pitfallx` (that you won't be ever using directly):

```
\mdfdefinestyle{pitfallstyle}{%
linecolor=gray,middlelinewidth=7pt,%
frametitlerule=false,%
%tikzsetting={shading=axis,top color=gray!10},
% apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
%shade,left color=white, right color=gray!20}}}, frametitlerulecolor=gray!60,
roundcorner=1pt,
splittopskip=1cm,
splitbottomskip=1cm,
bottomline=false,
leftline=false,
rightline=false,
backgroundcolor=gray!10,
frametitlerulewidth=0pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip, }
% changes in pitfall environment
\newenvironment{pitfall}
  {\begin{mdframed}[style=pitfallstyle]\pitfallx}
  {\endpitfallx\end{mdframed}}
```